# nginx reverse proxy UDP traffic (invalid parameter "udp")

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to host a Unifi controller behind a nginx reverse proxy. This works well except that I'm having troubles with the STUN protocol.

I'm using nginx 1.18 on Ubuntu 20.04. When I check the loaded modules for nginx it lists `--with-stream=dynamic` as available but when I try to use: `listen 3478 udp;` in my server block it fails with the following error message:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "udp" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/stream_unifi.example.com:7
```

The `stream_unifi.example.com` config is loaded in a `stream` context:

```
stream {
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/stream_*;
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing or do I need to compile nginx with some special flags myself?

Thank you!

---

Full output:

```
root@server:/etc/nginx/modules-available# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/nginx-5J5hor/nginx-1.18.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-compat --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module
root@server:/etc/nginx/modules-available# cat ../sites-available/stream_unifi.example.com
# Unifi STUN UDP Traffic
upstream unifi_stun {
        server 127.0.0.1:3478;
}

server {
    listen 3478 udp;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/acmetool.conf;

    location / {
                proxy_pass https://unifi_stun;
        proxy_responses 0;
    }
}
root@server:/etc/nginx/modules-available# nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "udp" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/stream_unifi.example.com:7
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
root@server:/etc/nginx/modules-available#
```

Comment: cant it be because you are not using the default port for udp?

Comment: What is the "default port" for UDP?

Comment: You can stop now. Trying to proxy STUN through nginx will just break it, as nginx will send a new UDP packet with its source address rather than the STUN client's. The STUN server needs to be directly connected to the Internet with a global IPv4 address. A 1-1 NAT might also work, but I wouldn't bet the company on it.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files, and check that you are not also loading the same file into an `http` context too.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks, that put me on the right path. I had an include in the nginx.conf http block that matched my stream configuration. I now moved it out of that directory and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few things wrong with my config and RichardSmith pointed me at the right direction.

My `nginx.conf` had the following blocks:

```
http {
        [other configuration options]
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

stream {
        [other configuration options]
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

1. I symlinked my "stream configuration" from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/stream_unifi.example.com` to `/etc/nginx/sites_enabled/stream_unifi.example.com`. This caused this configuration to be picked up by both the `http` and the `stream` block in the `nginx.conf` shown above. The fix is to change the include in the `stream` block to look like this:

```
stream {
        include /etc/nginx/stream-sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Then create this `stream-sites-enabled` directory and symlink `/etc/nginx/sites-available/stream_unifi.example.com` to that directory.

2. The stream configuration itself (`stream_unifi.example.com`) had some issues and has to look like this:

```
upstream unifi_stun {
        server 127.0.0.1:3478;
}

server {
    listen 3478 udp;
    proxy_pass unifi_stun;
    proxy_responses 0;
}
```

Hope that's helpful to someone else too.